# Spring JSP authorize tags always true, always hide

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

We're on the latest version of Spring. The project I'm working on is essentially a blog manager (This is a coding bootcamp capstone project) and for the life of us we can't figure out what's happening in Spring Security. Logging in appears to work fine, and Spring locks down the endpoints that we specify from regular users vs admin users. However, the Spring security tags don't seem to function in our JSPs. The `authorize` tag always hides content no matter who is logged in, and of course we'd like it to be displayed if an admin is logged in. Relevant JSP code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>

<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    <!-- stuff to hide -->
</sec:authorize>
```

Here's our `spring-security.xml` file:

```
<!-- #1 - Make security the default namespace -->
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- #2 - Make sure we don’t need authorization to get to the login or home page -->

    <http pattern="/home" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/img/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/login" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/contact" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/posts/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/post/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/pages/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/comments/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/js/**" security="none"/>

    <!-- #3 - Authentication/login form and protected endpoint configuration --> 
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">
        <!-- #3a - Login via html form, use Spring to do the security check --> 
        <!-- #3b - Use the login page at this endpoint --> 
        <!-- #3c - Redirect here if login fails --> 
        <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                    login-page="/login"
                    authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=1"/>
        <!-- #3d - Go back to home page when user logs out -->
        <logout logout-success-url="/home" />
        <!-- #3e - Access to these endpoints require admin role -->

        <!--new try NO! -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/addPost" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/addPage" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/comment/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <!--<intercept-url pattern="/post" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />-->
        <intercept-url pattern="/editPost/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

        <!-- #3f - Access to all other controller endpoints require user role -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>
    <!-- #4 - Authentication Manager config -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <!-- #4a - Authentication Provider - we’re using the JDBC service -->
        <authentication-provider>
            <!-- #4b - Tells Spring Security where to look for user information -->
            <!--       We use the dataSource defined in spring-persistence.xml  --> 
            <!--       and we give Spring Security the query to use to lookup   --> 
            <!--       the user’s credentials (get the password from the users  --> 
            <!--       tables and get the roles from the authorities table)     -->
            <jdbc-user-service id="userService"
                               data-source-ref="dataSource"
                               users-by-username-query=
          "select username, password, enabled from users where username=?"
                               authorities-by-username-query=
          "select username, authority from authorities where username=?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

and finally the filters from the `web.xml` file:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<!--         #1a - Intercept ALL requests to this application -->
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

In searching around, it looks like a lot of problems are caused by filter orders in `web.xml`, particularly with `site-mesh`, but we aren't using `site-mesh` and we don't have any other filters. We have also tried changing the JSP tag to `<sec:authorize access="permitAll()">` and it will still hide the element, no matter what element it is, who is logged in, or what JSP we put it in. 2 of us have spent 5 hours on this and we're at a complete loss for ideas at this point.

EDIT:

The problem ended up being with the `security="none"` in the http patterns at the top of `spring-security.xml`. As far as I can tell it prevents any Spring security filters from working properly on the url pattern specified. We fixed it by adding patterns we needed security features on to the `intercept-url`s.

Example:
`<http pattern="/home" security="none"/>`

move this down to the other intercept urls and change to:

`<url-intercept pattern="/home" access="permitAll">`

Comment: Which URLs are you going to?  I only ask because any JSPs rendered by going to "/home", "/posts", etc. (anything matching section #2 in your config) will not be able to use those tags.  The only JSPs where the tags will work are those rendered in response to "/admin", "/addPost", etc.

Comment: yeah we just figured that out and it fixed the problem per my edit. Thanks so much!